# How to check if file is a valid gz or not in Spark or Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have some files in my HDFS dir,  I want to process them using Spark, but the real problem I see when my process encounters with a corrupted .gz files, when ever there is a corrupted .gz files it taking hours to complete that run . Can someone tell how to solve this issue

Once solution I know not to copy a corrupted gz or move all non corrupted file to different location and make my job point to that Dir, but I was wondering can spark can handle those scenarios.

Comment: Have you looked at java.util.zip._?

https://gist.github.com/sasaki-shigeo/8431252

Comment: Use checksums when you put files on hdfs. Compare if they are equal. It's not Spark's job to differentiate if the file was completely uploaded or not.